# Override h1 anchor link color present in default theme

Tags: html, css

I'm basically trying to change the color of `<a>` tag present inside `<h1>` tag by adding custom CSS to my wordpress theme.

Following is rendered HTML

```
<div class='container'>
<header>
    <div class='site-logo-blog'>
        <span class='pull-left'><a href='http://x.com/blog/' title='x' rel='home'><img src='http://x.com/logo.png' alt='The X Blog'></a></span>
    </div>
  <h1 class='ph-title-blog'><a href="http://x.com/blog">The X Blog</a><span class='small ph-tagline'></span></h1>

  <div class="clear-both"></div>
</header>
</div>
```

I'm adding the following as custom CSS. But the anchor link color doesn't change.

```
h1 .ph-title-blog a:link {
    color: #6826B2 !important;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the `span` tag?

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP. As it stands it looks like your markup is invalid.

Comment: Posted the rendered HTML

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rz970457/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the space between `h1` and `.ph-title-blog`. Update to following.

```
h1.ph-title-blog a:link {
    color: #6826B2 !important;
}
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/8aKWMu1FDVHtRmQ45ck4?p=preview

Comment: @user709413 - I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: @user709413 - Have you specified `href` with `a` tag? If not, then use `h1.ph-title-blog a`

Comment: <a href= starts from the line 4 in the HTML render

Comment: @user709413 - Ok. Then your markup is incorrect. If you start a tag before any other tag then it needs to be closed after the other tag is closed i.e. `a` tag should be closed after `h1` tag is closed.

Comment: Yes. I did that correction now. Now I have two a tags. But the color is not changing.

Comment: @user709413 - It is working for me. Check - http://plnkr.co/edit/8aKWMu1FDVHtRmQ45ck4?p=preview

Comment: @user709413 - inspect in developer tools and check.